# How to execute method using spring beans

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I need findItemByPIdEndDate() method of the MngtImpl class to be invoked every 5000ms, but nothing appears to be happening. Am I missing something?

```
<bean id="findItemByPIdEndDate" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="MngtImpl"/>
  <property name="targetMethod" value="findItemByPIdEndDate"/>
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="50000"/>
</bean>
```

@matt b I've read some of this, everything is new to me here ..so I came with this .. and again its not working, what am I missing this time ?

```
<bean id="findItemByPIdEndDate" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="MngtImpl" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="findItemByPIdEndDate" />
</bean>

<bean id="compareDateTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="findItemByPIdEndDate" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="50000" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task, the [Chapter 23. Scheduling and Thread Pooling is your friend](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz). That said, here is a short summary.

First, define your `Job`:

```
<bean id="findItemByPIdEndDate" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="MngtImpl"/>
  <property name="targetMethod" value="findItemByPIdEndDate"/>
</bean>
```

Now, you need to schedule the job using a trigger and a `SchedulerFactoryBean`. For the trigger, I suggest to use a `SimpleTriggerBean` in your case:

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
  <!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="findItemByPIdEndDate" />
  <!-- 10 seconds -->
  <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
  <!-- repeat every 50 seconds -->
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="50000" />
</bean>
```

To finalize everything, set up the `SchedulerFactoryBean`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Whether the build failure is related to the new Spring configuration or not, this is another story.

Answer (score 4):

You need a lot more plumbing than that to make Quartz work. Just declaring the `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` on its own will do nothing.

However, Quartz is overkill for this, Java5+ can do this on its own. I suggest reading up on Spring's [ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean.html), which in combination with [MethodInvokingRunnable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/MethodInvokingRunnable.html), allows you to invoke your method periodically.

Comment: Could you please explain this more briefly, I don't know where should I be looking at this page you wrote as you said "You need a lot more plumbing than that to make Quartz work"

Comment: He's saying that Quartz is more complicated than what you need, and INSTEAD of using Quartz, read up on the ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean and MethodInvokingRunnable. I would agree, unless you have a need to use Quartz.

A ScheduledExecutorService will meet your needs much easier than using Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done so far is the equivalent of only instantiating a MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean() - essentially all you've done is created the Job. Now you need to have some configuration for how it's scheduled, and what triggers it.

Take a look at [the section in the Spring manual on Quartz](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz).